# jupyter notebook find and replace specific word

Tags: jupyter

When i search specific word in one cell such as word of 'apple',

It finds all words including word of 'apple'.

For example, in my code there are word of 'apple', 'apple_1', 'applebannana'.

How I can find only 'apple' word and replace only that word?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to find `apple` surrounded by whitespace boundaries on both sides.  If so, then you may use:

```
(?<!\S)apple(?!\S)
```